# how to set up this conditional route

Tags: ruby-on-rails, routes

So I have some documents that are accessible using the classic route

`/documents/6`

where 6 is the `:id` of the document

However, the same document can also be filed in **one or more groups**

However when I try to access the file through the group resource under: `groups/3` where 3 is the id, the url when clicking the file is still

`/documents/6`

I would like it to be something like

```
groups/3/documents/6
```

but only when I access the document from within that group...

How do I set-up a conditional route to make that nested route work?

Comment: Can you post your routes?

Comment: Take a look at nested resources https://guides.rubyonrails.org/routing.html#nested-resources

Comment: So that’s all I need to do just nest the documents route under groups? It will automatically use the correct document and group id ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To have both routes for same document you can declare route twice:

```rb
resources :documents
resources :groups do
  resources :documents
end
```

These will route to the same controller, but when the one with group is used - there'll be additional `group_id` param.

And to make these urls - use helper like:

```rb
group_document_path(group_id:1, id:123) # => /groups/1/documents/123
```